# a good way to install a new JDK 15 or higher which is on LTS on Mac Ventura 13.3.1a?

Tags: java, installation, java-home, macos-ventura

I am working on Mac Ventura 13.3.1a.
I am using JDK 15.02 and defining the JAVA_HOME in .zshrc as  like this

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 15.0.2)
```

Every thing is working fine. With the [new Changes in the Oracle JDK Installers (JDK 17, 11, and 8)](https://blogs.oracle.com/java/post/changes-in-the-oracle-jdk-installers)
what is the best means of installing a new JDK like JDK 17 or higher, while I have been using JDK 1.15.02, right now. Would it be downloading and running .dmg file or zip file and unzipping it in your convenient folder, which I am doing right now. ?

Comment: I use SDK man but is has known issues with Java if you are using Xcode (Xcode can't find the path because is expecting the default by system instead of the custom SDK man path) https://sdkman.io/

Comment: what is the purpose of java installed? I'm using jdk shipped with IntelliJ and didn't install anything else.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov
I am using Appium 2.0.0-beta66, Java Client 8.5.0, node 18.xx, Selenium-java 4.9.1, Selenium Server 3.141.59, TestNG 7.7.1, and JDK 1.15.0-02
I am using this set up for test automating Flutter mobile app on Android and Apple devices.

BTW, If I decide to use IntelliJ supplied one, some times, it may be having some incompatibilities with the above components I mentioned above. Also, to be truthful, I never tried to use JDK that way. Presently I am using the IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1.2 (Community Edition), the latest.